# NodeJS Express rest call

Tags: node.js, express

I am wondering if NodeJS allow app.use('/api', postRoute) and app.use('/api', authRoute) as middleware.

I am facing an issue where I think I am not allowed to use both /api in nodejs. The thing is when I change the second one to app.use('/apis', authRoute) and it works.

As you can see that even though post and auth js both have different routes, the Postman 1 is giving me the error. What am I missing here? Here is the code:

```
const postRoute = require('./routes/posts')
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth')
app.use('/api', postRoute)
app.use('/api', authRoute)

//post.js
router.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.json('Hello, world')
   
})

//auth.js
router.get('/reg', (req, res) => {
    res.json('Hello, it is working')
})

//postman 1
http://localhost:5000/api/reg

{
    "message": {
        "stringValue": "\"reg\"",
        "kind": "ObjectId",
        "value": "reg",
        "path": "_id",
        "reason": {}
    }
}

//postman 2
http://localhost:5000/api

"Hello, world"
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The error looks more like a mongoose-error. What exactly are you doing inside the `/reg`-handler?

Comment: thanks. the /reg handler is just a simple res.json('Hello, it is working'). It is shown in the code shown above. Thanks

Comment: That's why I was wondering - are you using mongoose somewhere else in a middleware? Where is this error coming from?

Comment: const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors =  require("cors");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const connectDB = require("./dbconfig/dbconfig");
const postRoute = require('./routes/posts')
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth')
dotenv.config()

connectDB()
const port = process.env.port || 5000
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use('/api', postRoute)
app.use('/api', authRoute)

app.listen(port,() => {
    console.log(`Listening to part ${port}...`)
})

Comment: I don't think I have any middleware in the server.js as the code shown above. Hopefully, I am missing something here.Thanks